# append without restarting the array from the beginning each time

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(50,4)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# LOOPING BY CHUNKS, STORING EACH CHUNK IN A NP ARRAY INSIDE A LIST
ix = 0
chunk = 10
arrays = []
for iy in range(chunk, len(df)+chunk, chunk):
    arrays.append(df.iloc[ix:iy])
    ix = iy
    print(arrays)
```

The issue is that when I print the arrays, it starts from the begining each time, when I need it to start the next array where the previous one stopped.
To clarify, in this example I have 1 array with 10 rows, then the first array is printed again with the next 10 rows, then both are printed and the next array is added etc... I would like to get rid of the repetition part(not only in print but in the loop overall) but couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just mixed up the variables to use to subset the data. Try something like this:

```
# LOOPING BY CHUNKS, STORING EACH CHUNK IN A NP ARRAY INSIDE A LIST
ix = 0
chunk = 10
arrays = []
for x in range(0, len(df), chunk):
    array = df.iloc[x: x+chunk]
    arrays.append(array)
    print(array)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I don't really understand the differences between the two codes, do you happend to know a tutorial that covers these differences ? or any type of resource

Comment: the key different is in line `df.iloc[x: x+chunk]`, we want x to start from zero and increase by `chunk` in every iteration. Sorry, I don't know about tutorial on this

Comment: Thanks, I see. Is it possible to change the step from chunk to something variable ? So that all the arrays are not the same size, but depending on the rows caracteristics, adding them to the chunk or no ?